# View all 32 possible Binary combinations for 5 digits

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have 5 digits

```
A,B,C,D,E
```

Is it possible in SQL to view all the possible Binary combinations for them? 
(Not the list of 120 possible permutations, just the 32 possible combinations in SQL http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-combinations.html)

Thus

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   0   0
1   1   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0 etc
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT x FROM (VALUES('0'),('1')) AS y(x)
)
SELECT A = x.x, B = x2.x, C = x3.x, D = x4.x, E = x5.x, 
       [binary] = x.x + x2.x + x3.x + x4.x + x5.x
FROM x
CROSS JOIN x AS x2
CROSS JOIN x AS x3
CROSS JOIN x AS x4
CROSS JOIN x AS x5;
```

Or, more lazily and less explicitly:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT x FROM (VALUES('0'),('1')) AS y(x)
)
SELECT A = x.x, B = x2.x, C = x3.x, D = x4.x, E = x5.x, 
       [binary] = x.x + x2.x + x3.x + x4.x + x5.x
FROM x, x AS x2, x AS x3, x AS x4, x AS x5;
```

Results:

```
A   B   C   D   E   binary
-   -   -   -   -   ------
0   0   0   0   0   00000
0   1   0   0   0   01000
0   0   1   0   0   00100
0   1   1   0   0   01100
0   0   0   1   0   00010
0   1   0   1   0   01010
0   0   1   1   0   00110
0   1   1   1   0   01110
1   0   0   0   0   10000
1   1   0   0   0   11000
1   0   1   0   0   10100
1   1   1   0   0   11100
1   0   0   1   0   10010
1   1   0   1   0   11010
1   0   1   1   0   10110
1   1   1   1   0   11110
0   0   0   0   1   00001
0   1   0   0   1   01001
0   0   1   0   1   00101
0   1   1   0   1   01101
0   0   0   1   1   00011
0   1   0   1   1   01011
0   0   1   1   1   00111
0   1   1   1   1   01111
1   0   0   0   1   10001
1   1   0   0   1   11001
1   0   1   0   1   10101
1   1   1   0   1   11101
1   0   0   1   1   10011
1   1   0   1   1   11011
1   0   1   1   1   10111
1   1   1   1   1   11111
```